# Is "limited overclocking" supported by Ivy Bridge Xeon?

Tags: overclocking, sandy-bridge, xeon, ivy-bridge

Intel Core i5 and i7 desktop processors in the Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge families support [limited overclocking](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/sandy-bridge-core-i7-2600k-core-i5-2500k,2833-9.html), where you can push the turbo boost multiplier to 4 bins above the standard.

For example, [Core i5-2500](http://ark.intel.com/products/52209/Intel-Core-i5-2500-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz) (non-K) has a nominal multiplier of 33x and a turbo boost multiplier of 37x (1 core active). On supported motherboards (P67, Z68, etc), you can overclock it to 41x (4.1 GHz at the standard 100 MHz base clock).

The Intel [Xeon E3-1200 v2 series](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/xeon-e3-benchmark-review,3258-2.html) server processors are very similar to the quad core Ivy Bridge desktop processors. Many desktop motherboards support these Ivy Bridge Xeon processors.

Here is my question: When used with desktop motherboards that support overclocking, do the Xeon E3-1200 v2 series processors support limited overclocking, just like their desktop counterparts? For example, can I run the [E3-1230 v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/65732/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1230V2-8M-Cache-3_30-GHz) at 41x (37x + 4x)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, limited overclocking is not supported. The E3-1230V2 has a 37x multi for cores 1 and 2 and a 35x multi for cores 3 and 4. When stressed across all 4 cores 35x.

108 BCLK is possible with the above multipliers.